# Azure Search Suggestions don't catch missing prefix

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

When sending a phrase to the Azure Search service, using Suggest method,
the results are only phrases start with the search term.
Even when using "FuzzyMatching"

for example "ap" will return "aplle" and "april" but not "rap"
Is it possible to get any phrase contain the search term ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that Azure Search does not allow for the ability to do this type of contain (or wildcard) search for suggestions.  However, one thing that we will be releasing (hopefully towards the end of next week) is something called custom analyzers.  Custom analyzers allow you to do not only this, but other types of analysis on your data.  For example, you can create a field and tell us that it should allow for prefix or suffix matching.  You can also choose to do regex style queries against your field.

I do want to caveat this with a bit of a warning though.  If you set your field to allow for prefix or suffix search we can get results quite quickly because if we know that you want us to either look at the start or end of the word, we can build our inverted index appropriately to handle this very quickly.  However, for things like generic contain (or even regex) it is more of a brute force type of search and if you have significant content, this could have an impact on the latency of your queries.

Hopefully that will help you do what you need here and if you want to keep an eye out for this, we will be posting content on this at our documentation page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/search/

Liam